# Remove workspace when no connection to tfs

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, workspace

I have a local vm with Visual Studio 2015 community edition. This was previously connected to a VSTS TFS collection - to which I no longer have access.

I want to connect VS to a new VSTS collection but each time a load Visual Studio I get the message "TF14061: The workspace xxx does not exist"

[image]

How can I prevent VS from looking for the workspace? I have trued tf workspace /delete commands where I pass the collection url as a param but this then prompts me to login and my credentials are no longer valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) to remove old source control workspace binding.

Or you can try to [delete TFVC and VS local cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/), then try it again.